# How to Bind to Another Control Property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, charts

I am using the WPF Charting ToolKit via the namespaces:

```
xmlns:ChartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:VisualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

I have a chart control in which I generate a random color for each time a `Lineseries` plot is undertaken. I remove the data point markers and colorize using the following style

```
<Style x:Key="LineDataPointStyle" 
        TargetType="ChartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="NaN"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" 
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource ColorBrushConverter}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ChartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
             <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `LineSeries` is defined via

```
<ChartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                            AnimationSequence="FirstToLast"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                            DataPointStyle="{StaticResource LineDataPointStyle}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}"
                            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}"/>
```

Now, this works fine but the legend markers display a different color to the random one I generate for the `LineSeries`. I want the same color to be displayed for the legend item for the `LineSeries` and the `Lineseries` itself. So, I have styled the legend item as below

```
<Style x:Key="TestSuiteLegendItemStyle" 
      TargetType="{x:Type ChartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ChartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
             <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Rectangle Width="8" 
                              Height="8" 
                              Fill="{Binding Background}" 
                              Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush}" 
                              StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                   <VisualizationToolkit:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </StackPanel>
             </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My question is *how can I 'bind' the `Rectangle.Fill` in the `TestSuiteLegendItemStyle` style so that it is the same color as the `LineSeries` as set by the `LineDataPointStyle` defined above?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. I have tried setting a `DependencyProperty` that holds the `Background` color of my plot as suggested below via*

```
<Style x:Key="LineDataPointStyle" 
        TargetType="ChartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background" 
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource ColorBrushConverter}}"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

*Where the I have ammended the converter (as marked) so that I can store the randomly generated background color and then use this in my legend*

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Brush b = new SolidColorBrush(Utils.GenerateRandomColor());
        MultiChartExtensions.BackgroundBrushProperty = b; <= how to set the dependency property?
        return b;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*where the Dependency Property (DP) is defined as*

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundBrushProperty;
public static void SetBackgroundBrush(DependencyObject DepObject, Brush value)
{
    DepObject.SetValue(BackgroundBrushProperty, value);
}

public static Brush GetBackgroundBrush(DependencyObject DepObject)
{
    return (Brush)DepObject.GetValue(BackgroundBrushProperty);
}
```

*I would then look to set the legend background via this DP via*

```
<Style x:Key="TestSuiteLegendItemStyle" 
      TargetType="{x:Type ChartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ChartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
             <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Rectangle Width="8" 
                              Height="8" 
                              Fill="{Binding MultiChart:MultiChartExtensions.BackgroundBrushProperty}" 
                              Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush}" 
                              StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                   <VisualizationToolkit:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </StackPanel>
             </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`Part I. Binding in ControlTemplate`**

If you want to use *Binding* in a `ControlTemplate`, you should use following construction:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type SomeControl}">
    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
```

Quoted from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx):

> A `TemplateBinding` is an optimized form of a Binding for template scenarios, analogous to a Binding constructed with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}.`

*`Notes about using TemplateBinding`*

`TemplateBinding` doesn’t work outside a template or outside its VisualTree property, so you can’t even use TemplateBinding inside a template’s trigger. Furthermore, TemplateBinding doesn’t work when applied to a Freezable (for mostly artificial reasons), for example - `VisualBrush`. In such cases it is possible to use Binding like this:

```
<FreezableControl Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                     Path=Background}" />
```

Also, you can always use an alternative for `TemplateBinding`:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                          Path=Background}" />
```

As another possibility, you can also try the following:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type SomeControl}}, 
                          Path=Background}" />
```

**`Part II. Notes about your version`**

In your case, this may cause a conflict of names in the `ControlTemplate`, because you already are using Binding background is for Border. Therefore, remove it this *Binding* for a `Border`, or use another property, such as `Tag` or *attached* dependency property for binding Background color.

*`Example of using`*

Instead `ChartingToolkit` controls, took as a basis `Button` control, because it's easier to demonstrate the idea of ​​this styles.

**`Solution 1: using Tag`**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TestButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <!-- Here we are set Tag for Border Background -->
                    <Border Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Width="24" 
                                       Height="24" 
                                       Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" 
                                       Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Name="TestButton"
            Style="{StaticResource TestButtonStyle}"
            Content="Test"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Tag="Green"
            Background="Aquamarine"
            Width="100"
            Height="100" />
</Grid>
```

`Output`

[image]

Here for `Rectangle`, set two colors: default for `Rectangle`, in Tag for `Border`. I do not find this a good solution, and here's why:

- If a Border and Rectangle need to set different values, such as: Background, BorderThickness, BorderBrush, etc. one `Tag` is not enough.
- With one name property must be clearly its purpose, one name "Tag" us to nothing says.

Of these disadvantages can be concluded that we should find an alternative, as an alternative I use a extender-class with the *attached* dependency properties.

Extender class `ButtonExt.cs`

```
public static class ButtonExt
{
    #region RectangleBackground Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RectangleBackgroundProperty;

    public static void SetRectangleBackground(DependencyObject DepObject, Brush value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(RectangleBackgroundProperty, value);
    }

    public static Brush GetRectangleBackground(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Brush)DepObject.GetValue(RectangleBackgroundProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region RectangleBorderBrush Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RectangleBorderBrushProperty;

    public static void SetRectangleBorderBrush(DependencyObject DepObject, Brush value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(RectangleBorderBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public static Brush GetRectangleBorderBrush(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Brush)DepObject.GetValue(RectangleBorderBrushProperty);
    }

    #endregion       

    #region Button Constructor

    static ButtonExt()
    {
        #region RectangleBackground

        PropertyMetadata BrushPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent);

        RectangleBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RectangleBackground",
                                                            typeof(Brush),
                                                            typeof(ButtonExt),
                                                            BrushPropertyMetadata);

        #endregion

        #region RectangleBorderBrush

        RectangleBorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RectangleBorderBrush",
                                                            typeof(Brush),
                                                            typeof(ButtonExt),
                                                            BrushPropertyMetadata);

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TestButtonExtensionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Pink" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding PropertiesExtension:ButtonExt.RectangleBackground}" 
                                       Stroke="{TemplateBinding PropertiesExtension:ButtonExt.RectangleBorderBrush}"
                                       Width="30" 
                                       Height="30" />

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TestButtonExtensionStyle}"
            PropertiesExtension:ButtonExt.RectangleBackground="Aquamarine"
            PropertiesExtension:ButtonExt.RectangleBorderBrush="Black"
            Content="Test" />
</Grid>
```

`Output`

[image]

**`Part III. Setting values for dependency properties`**

When you create and register your *attached* dependency property, you must declare the Set and Get methods to work with him:

```
public static void SetRectangleBackground(DependencyObject DepObject, Brush value)
{
    DepObject.SetValue(RectangleBackgroundProperty, value);
}

public static Brush GetRectangleBackground(DependencyObject DepObject)
{
    return (Brush)DepObject.GetValue(RectangleBackgroundProperty);
}
```

Then work with them will be as follows:

*`Set`*

```
ButtonExt.SetRectangleBackground(MyButton, Brushes.Red);
```

*`Get`*

```
Brush MyBrush = ButtonExt.GetRectangleBackground(MyButton);
```

But in our case, it's not so simple. When I used the attached dependency property problems in updating values ​​were not. But in our case, the property is in the template, and in my case there was no update `Button`. I tried to set `Mode=TwoWay`, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, in Binding and in the property declaration, `GetBindingExpression().UpdateTarget()`, but it was useless.

Note that for the property setting a *new* value, and notification from the template is not, that the property has been updated. Maybe I'm wrong, and you have will work, or maybe it's made specifically, for example to avoid memory leaks.

In any case, it is better not to update the dependency property directly, and bind to it the property of the `Model` and in the `ViewModel` to set the value.

Example:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TestButtonExtensionStyle}"
        adp:ButtonExt.RectangleBackground="{Binding Path=Model.RectBackground,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        adp:ButtonExt.RectangleBorderBrush="{Binding Path=Model.RectBorderBrush,
                                                     Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

where `RectBackground` and `RectBorderBrush` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

As an alternative in this case, do not use dependency properties and use the `DataTemplate` for the control. `DataTemplate` ideal for MVVM, very flexible and dynamic.

For example, work with `DataTemplate`, you can see my answers:

[Make (create) reusable dynamic Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839096/make-create-reusable-dynamic-views)

[One ViewModel for UserControl and Window or separate ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868047/one-viewmodel-for-usercontrol-and-window-or-separate-viewmodels/20873276#20873276)

Comment: Thanks again for another reply, I am learning a lot from your answers. I have seen you mention using `Tag` before, but here, it is not clear to me how you intend it to be used to incorporate the `Background`? This is a personal project so I will attempt to implement you suggestions after work tonight... Thanks again.

Comment: Note, I have asked a more generic question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293363/change-the-color-displayed-in-wpf-charting-toolkit-legend which has an active bounty. The answer to this question will be a combination of what I have done in my new question above and your answer... I will happily award you the bounty later if your suggestions work.

Comment: @Killercam: Please see my edit. Instead `ChartingToolkit` controls, took as a basis `Button` control, because it's easier to demonstrate the idea of ​​this styles and I personally have not worked with `ChartingToolkit`. If there are problems with your implementation `ChartingToolkit` or will further questions, please ask.

Comment: @Killercam: I wanted to ask, if you helped my example or were any problems?

Comment: Hi, I unfortunately have not had time to implement this yet. The question I linked above has a bounty attached to it. If you answer that and merely link to this question I will award you 50 rep as you are always very helpful to me and you deserve it! Hope you are well and thanks again for your help. As soon as I implement this I will accept the answer...

Comment: @Killercam: Thank you for your responsiveness and for the fact that you respect and appreciate others work. I will post this answer in bounty in another question, if it really helps you.

Comment: Hi Anatoliy, I have edited the question as I can't seem to get this to work. I appreciate you have spent time helping me already so understand if you do not have time to extend your answer/advice. I would not say I am new to this, but this side of MVVM I am still struggling with and probably shouldn't be!

Comment: @Killercam: Okay, give me time for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set `x:Name` on LineSeries control:

```
<ChartingToolkit:LineSeries x:Name="lineSeries"/>
```

Then you can bind in `TestSuiteLegendItemStyle` via binding using `ElementName`:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=lineSeries}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I should have know this method! I have tried this and it is now setting the fill to transparent. Have you any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Make sure binding is not breaking. I suspect both controls does not lie in same Visual Tree. Transparent might be default color. Check output window for any binding error.

Comment: This does not work. For some reason it is not binding to the specifid Element via `ElementName`...