# MVVMLight within another MVVMLight project

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I am working on a MVVMLight / WPF project and need to add a chunk of functionality which will include multiple views and viewmodels.  I know this same bit of functionality will be used in other projects in the near future so I would like to make this functionality its own project that I can add to other solutions as needed wiuth little or no modification.

I started by adding a second MVVMLight project (Beta), removing the standard MainWindow.xaml and MainViewModel.cs files and created a simple UserControl and associated View Model.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Beta.View.TestView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        DataContext="{Binding Test_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator} }">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeMessage}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties

    public string WelcomeMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the TestViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public TestViewModel()
    {

    }

    #endregion Constructors
}
```

I am able to add Beta as a reference to the original project (Alpha) and display the view by inserting the view into a stack panel like so:

```
<StackPanel Name="MasterStackPanel"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <beta:TestView />
</StackPanel>
```

Everything appears to work properly when doing this.  The issue I am having is when I try to bind a Property from TestViewModel to TestView.

In TestView, if I do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
```

the TestView displays correctly at runtime.  But when I bind the TextBlock to a property like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeMessage}" />
```

The message does not display and the locator for Beta appears to be ignored (the datacontext is not being bound) and I am getting the following error from Snoop:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'WelcomeMessage' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=51013215)'. BindingExpression:Path=WelcomeMessage; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=51013215); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test_VM' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=22749765)'. BindingExpression:Path=Test_VM; DataItem='ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=22749765); target element is 'TestView' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

I believe this means that the binding of Test_VM & WelcomeMessage are trying to be found via the Alpha Locator and not the Beta Locator.  I am using the ViewModelLocator that is created by default when starting a MVVMLight project in each project.

Is it possible to have an second 'Locator' and if so what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like User Control Library...

Comment: `which will include multiple views and viewmodels` - maybe it's better use the `DataTemplate` instead of UserControl; [`Example`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839096/make-create-reusable-dynamic-views/21304839#21304839)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only have one Locator in the *application root* of the system and use the "MvvmLightLibs" library in the library project and reference it in the alpha project and add a TestViewModel-Property in the locator.